# Exported dataset XML viewer

Tags: xml, dataset, viewer

I have a strongly typed ADO.NET dataset containing several tables exported as an XML file. Is there a program that would allow me to view the data in the XML file in a tabular manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oxygen XML does what I need: http://www.oxygenxml.com/